# Как декодировать URL code в Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, url

Преобразование текста в URL:

```
import urllib.parse
print(urllib.parse.quote_plus("Hello, World!"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть [quote_plus](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus), то будет [unquote_plus](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_plus):

```
print(urllib.parse.unquote_plus('Hello%2C+World%21'))
# Hello, World!
```